# Visual Studio VSTO 32-bit and 64-bit builds

Tags: visual-studio, outlook, vsto, office-addins

I am writing an Outlook VSTO addin using Visual Studio.  The addin uses SQLite. It needs a dll called SQLite.interop.dll.  This comes in a 32-bit version and 64-bit version, and Outlook wants the correct version.  If the end user is running a 32-bit version of Office on a 64-bit CPU, Outlook needs the 32-bit version of the dll, and the 64-bit version doesn't work.  Three questions:

1. Is there a way of detecting whether the user is running a 32-bit or 64-bit version of Office?
2. Is it possible in Visual Studio to do two builds of the same project, one containing the 32-bit dll and one containing the 64-bit dll, or do I need two separate projects?
3. Is there some other way of managing this?

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 1):

Your addin is always running with the same bitness as Outlook, just compile it as "Any CPU".

Keep both dlls (or embed them as resource), and at run-time determine the bitness by evaluating the size of the IntPtr type - 4 for 32 bit, and 8 for 64. Then extract/load the dll of the right bitness.